# unable to get macros in notepad++ newer version

Tags: notepad++, text-editors

I am using notepad++ 5.9x, And i currently installed notepad 6.0. But i am unable to see my customized settings in the newer version. (I have not uninstalled the previous version, I downloaded 7zip format of notepad++).

please help me in order to get back my 1)Macros 2) keyboard shortcuts(customized)

Thanks and regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, Notepad++ macros, styles, keyboard shortcuts are **not** saved in its install path, but in a junction path: **C:\Users\[USER_NAME]\AppData\Roaming\Notepad++**

1. Press the windows button on your keyboard and type `%AppData%`, press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
2. Go to the Notepad++ folder of your old installation and copy paste all the xml files (and plugins if you have them) into your new version of Notepad++

This should work. I've ported my Notepad++ styles between three different systems using this approach.