# Why does Notepad++ turn commas into semicolons when copying+pasting, and how can we prevent it from happening?

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

I have a report from someone asking a programming question on StackOverflow that when they pasted valid code

```
[(1, "google"), (2, "facebook"), (3, "apple")]
```

from Notepad++ into StackOverflow, it appeared as

```
[(1; "google"); (2; "facebook"); (3; "apple")]
```

(and they did not notice until after they submitted their question).

How should Notepad++ users configure Notepad++ to not mangle text like this?

Comment: Works fine for me. I just typed out what you posted here and the copied it from Notepad++ to the answer box and it worked fine.

Comment: Did you set Notepad++ to CSV mode or something like that? `;` is the CSV field separator in some locales. What are the Notepad++ and Windows locale settings?

Comment: Any add-ons installed to Notepad++?  Some code helpers may be able to automatically "correct" the commas to semicolons.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have the [latest version](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/download/v6.1.2.html) of Notepad++. With the default settings, there should be no issues copy-pasting code onto StackOverflow. I do it almost everyday and the snippet you posted works just fine.

If you're worried about porting all your preferences/styles/shortcuts and all other customization to the new version, just follow the [steps shown here](https://superuser.com/questions/406110/unable-to-get-macros-in-notepad-newer-version/414473#414473)